# margin-bottom not showing up in right place

Tags: css, html, css-float, margin

I have simple example with a header and content divs. I want there to be a 10 pixel margin after the header div, but it is showing up after the content div. The header div has two floating divs. Following is the code:

```
<style type="text/css"
div {border: 1px solid red;}
#container{width:680px;}
#header{margin-bottom:10px; background-color:yellow;}
#title{float:left;}
#link{float:right;}
#header_clear{clear:both;}
</style>

<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="title">Header Title</div>
        <div id="link" style="float:right;">
            <a href="http://www.apple.com" target="_blank">Link</a>
        </div>
        <div id="header_clear"/>
    </div>
    
    <div id="content" style="background-color:brown;">
        This is the body.
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's what it looks like. You can see that the 10px margin is below the content div instead of the header div.

[image: screen capture showing the issue]

[margin-bottom not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142430/margin-bottom-not-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
div {border: 1px solid red;}
#container{width:680px;}
#header{margin-bottom:10px; background-color:yellow;}
#title{float:left;}
#link{float:right;}
#header_clear{clear:both;}
</style>

<div id="container">
 <div id="header">
    <div id="title">Header Title</div>
    <div id="link">
        <a href="http://www.apple.com" target="_blank">Link</a>
    </div>
    <div id="header_clear"></div>
 </div>

 <div id="content" style="background-color:brown;">
    This is the body.
 </div>
</div>
```

Seems it didnt like the self closing div

Comment: To expand a bit, this: `<div id="header_clear"/>` isn't going to do what you think when the browser parses the DOM. `div` elements are not self closing like that if the document is being served as `text/html` [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8AE3/3/)