# background color not filling entire div

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am having a problem in filling the entire center content (`div`) with a background color.

I want to fill element with id `body-content` with the blue color but its not actually stretching to full height.

[image]

`HTML code`

```
<div id="body-content">

<iframe id="promo-video" width="40%" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="margin-bottom: 20px;"></iframe>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var y_pos = $('#search-panel').position().top;
    $('#promo-video').css('top',y_pos);
    });
    function sho(a){
        if (a=='1'){
            document.getElementById('criteria-1').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('criteria-2').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('criteria-3').style.display = "none";
        }
        else if (a=='2'){
            document.getElementById('criteria-1').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('criteria-2').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('criteria-3').style.display = "none";
        }
        else if (a=='3'){
            document.getElementById('criteria-1').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('criteria-2').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('criteria-3').style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>
<div id="search-boxes">

    <div id="search-panel">
    <form id="search-form" name="search-form" onsubmit="return false;">
    <fieldset style="margin-bottom:8px;">
    <legend><i>Find By</i></legend>
        <input type="radio" name="sp" onclick="sho(1);" checked/>A 
        <input type="radio" name="sp" onclick="sho(2);"/>B
        <input type="radio" name="sp" onclick="sho(3);"/>C
    </fieldset>
    <p>
            <select name="spe" id="criteria-1">
                <option value="g">G</option>
                <option value="c">C</option>
                <option value="ge">Ge</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" style="width:97%;vertical-align:center;display:none;height:24px;padding-left:8px;" placeholder="Or find a.." id="criteria-2"/>
            <input type="text" style="width:97%;vertical-align:center;display:none;height:24px;padding-left:8px;" placeholder="Or find b.." id="criteria-3"/>
    </p>        
            <select name="city" style="width:49%;">
                <option value="any-city">In City</option>
                <option value="mumbai">Mumbai</option>
                <option value="nyc">New York</option>
            </select>
            <select name="locality" style="width:49%;">
                <option value="anywhere">Near Area</option>
                <option value="vasant-vihar">Vasant Vihar</option>
                <option value="andheri">Andheri</option>
            </select>
            <br><br>
        <input type="submit" class="button_g" name="submit-search" value="Search for A">
    </form>
    </div>
</div><!-- End of Search boxes -->

</div><!-- End of body content -->
```

`CSS code`

```
#search-boxes{
    margin: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 8%;
    clear: both;
    width: 450px;
}

#search-panel{
    border: 6px solid #c6e7f8;
}
#search-panel{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Segoe UI Semibold", sans-serif;
}

#search-boxes select{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
}

#promo-video{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 8%;
    border: 6px solid #d9d9d9;
}

#body-content{
    background-color: #e9f6fc;
/*  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e9f6fc 50%, white);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( to bottom, #e9f6fc 50%, white);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( to bottom, #e9f6fc 50%, white);
    background: -o-linear-gradient( to bottom, #e9f6fc 50%, white);
*/  margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I tried searching for the problem and found a solution, that `clear` should be used to make floating items behave normally. But that too doesn't work. What am I missing?

Another problem was with the linear gradient, I wanted blue to extend till 50% height, but that fills upto 90%, when the blue color fills the entire `body-content`.

Comment: For the gradient problem, check this at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/edibok/5/), code is at http://jsbin.com/edibok/5/edit

Comment: If there's a separate, unrelated problem, create a separate question for it. Each question should be focused on a single, specific problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
#body-content {overflow: hidden;}
```

That forces the `body-content` div to wrap around its floated contents. There are other methods for enclosing floats, but this tends to be the easiest.

Note, however, that because your `iframe` is set to `position: absolute;`, nothing will clear that except a height on the container, which is rarely a good idea. It would be better to float that too.

Comment: exactly. Can you please tell other methods too. please.

Comment: Here is a list of them: http://pageaffairs.com/notebook/containing-floats . I have updated my post, too.

Comment: and i am editing my question, with another problem too with the linear gradient. Please have a look

Comment: +1 thank you  this answer solved 2 problems for me. One of them was for the original background not filling as per the question. And the other was for the bottom margin not working in a situation - I made an enclosing div with your css and the bottom margin came back - related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142430/margin-bottom-not-working

Answer (score 0):

First off, that code doesn't generate anything like that screenshot for me (frame is on top of the search boxes and the blue background goes further down).
But replacing the `position:absolute;` in the `#promo-video` style to `float: left;` and adding another `float:left` to `#search-boxes` generated something similar to what you have.

In that situation, correcting your issue is simply a matter of adding `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` below the closing tag for `search-boxes`>

i.e.
Use floats to get the layout you want.

Comment: but that did for me and the above answer solved the problem. Any suggestions for the linear gradient problem?